# How should I handle me and my car being mistaken for someone else with the same car who behaves inappropriately?

Tags: colleagues, human-resources, conflict

A colleague working in a different apartment has the exact same car as I have (same model and color and the only two of the brand at my office). The only difference is the chairs, but I understand this is not something that really makes them stand out from each other.

Now the other owner is a very rude. He will park in visitor's spots, which we're not allowed to park in, and he'll park in such a manor as to occupy two space and be completely crooked.  They have even damaged other cars before. All of this while driving a particularly tiny car.

Apparently my face is much more associated with the car than his, as I've been getting all the complaints, rants and threats over his parking. Two months ago there even was an incident where two of my colleagues completely duct-taped my car because they thought it was his. (I had permission to park on the visitor spots that day because I had to carry in heavy 
stuff.) Leaving all my windows with sticky stains that took me hours to remove.

Should I approach this guy? Should I make changes to the appearance of my car?

What would be the best way to approach this guy? Should I talk to him myself or notify HR? According to colleagues who have talked to him, he has been asked to act normal multiple times but has never improved.

Comment: Don't people recognize the licence plates are different? Maybe you can ask managment to send out a *general* reminder to park correctly and not use the visitor spots. (And if you are allowed to use the visitor spots for a set time and task, put up a quick sign saying something like "I am unloading X and will be moving the car at Y am.")

Comment: I would complain to HR just for the part "my colleagues completely duct-taped my car"...

Comment: I would politely tell these colleagues who duct-taped my car that if they are incapable of reading a license plate, next time they will be sued for property damage and will have to pay for a professional removal and potentially repair on the car paint.

Comment: find ways to make your car look distinct. i.e. buy a cover and place it every morning

Comment: @Dominik: But first the colleagues would be asked politely to remove the duct tape, without leaving any traces or damages, or else.

Comment: @Dominik Agreed, but that kinda implies that they duct-taped the wrong car... which in turn implies that there is a _right_ car to duct tape. Which is not the case.

Comment: The duct-tape thing is ......... completely bizarre.  Did you take legal action?

Comment: @Fattie Because I have no idea who the other owner is. Over 400 people work here. When people come to me I explain it's not my car and that it's parked somewhere else, when I can't give them the answer of who's it is, the angry mob darts off to apparently try and go find him.

Comment: Oh you say you don't know who it is.  Look, you should INSTANTLY tell HR about this issue.  So do that.  Also just LOUD AND CLEAR tell everyone that there's another car like yours.  Do not worry about "offending" the other unknown person, be loud and clear about it.

Comment: @Fattie HR knows about the tape, the colleagues who did it helped me clear some off my rear window so I could drive again and that was enough of a solution to them. They have wrapped completely in bubble wrap before and HR was fine with it.

Comment: Hi @JaneDoe1337.  To be honest, what you describe is so - bizarre, actually scary - I would, literally, like I'm not exaggerating, I would *run away* from that company, as if I was in a horror movie. Now we have the bubble story.  Is it possible you're "letting people walk over you" - maybe you should be more forceful.  Your HR team should be institutionalized.  Good luck and hope it works out.

Comment: @Fattie I agree I'm not the most hands on person when it comes to these things. I am the avoiding type. But it is bizarre yes. I am working on leaving but simply quitting is not an option if you have tiny mouths to feed. Thanks.

Comment: you're lucky they are tiny!  :)  wait until they are HUGE  :)

Comment: Does not make sense you "According to colleagues who have talked to him."

Comment: @Paparazzi I know in what building he works, 120 people work in the building. The colleagues have no idea about his name either, they just hit him up every time he exits/enters the car.

Comment: TBH - if anyone vandalized my car with duct tape, I'd call the police first and HR second.

Comment: @NoBackingDown You're more generous than me. I'd have immediately confronted the two colleagues and demanded that they get the tape off my car, themselves, or pay out of pocket -- immediately -- for a professional to do it. Then, while they were doing that, I'd have gone to HR to report that utterly inappropriate behavior.

Comment: HR will care very quickly when you sue them for damages to your car caused by their employees and their failure to put a stop to these kinds of property damage.

Comment: Get a picture of your car, and a picture of the other guy's car. Send them both in an email to everyone in the company. "For your information, there are two very similar cars that can be found in the parking lot at times. Please do not confuse them if you are interested in interacting with one or the other car or owner. You may notice that they have different license plates and different seats? That is because *they are not the same car*."

Answer (score 21):

Honestly, you should be going to HR over the other 2 colleagues duct taping your car. That is utterly unacceptable.

Now, it's clear from your question that *you* haven't spoken to the colleague who can't park directly yet. I think you should mention to him the incident, and explain to him that his lack of care with his car is now causing you to suffer. Possibly explain to him that the parking rules apply to everyone. I wouldn't mention his bad parking, but do mention the fact that the visitor spots are for visitors only. Most people will try to better themselves if they see what they're doing is having an adverse effect on another person.

If this doesn't work, go to HR. Specifically mention him parking in the visitor spaces. If he damages another persons car, that isn't an issue for HR. That's an issue for the insurance companies/the two parties involved.

Comment: It turns out that "HR" *knows about* - no, really - the duct tape incident, and the same people more or less regularly, apparently, attack cars!

Comment: @Fattie Not so much regularly as twice occassions now but yes, they indeed know.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 If HR knows about the issue and does nothing, there may be some legal liability there. I would make it clear that you're not taking this lightly and possibly mention considering getting the police involved or taking legal action against the criminals / perpetrators. HR is there to protect the company, saying something that might imply the company ending up in a lawsuit should make make a few alarm bells go off in their head and lead them to do everything in their power to sort this issue out.

Comment: I'm considering downvoting this for the second paragraph. If people have spoken to him about it multiple times, I really don't see why another person speaking to him would change anything (especially if it's just a coworker). To me, his behaviour thus far makes it clear that he doesn't fall into the "most people" who "will try to better themselves", and speaking to him directly is likely to just end up being a frustrating experience.

Comment: @Dukeling I see where you're coming from, but from personal experience, when someone says "I talked to them already" it can mean a variety of different things. You'll never know unless you talk to them yourself.

Comment: @DCON someone that park to take two places in visitor know what he's doing. For me it way enough to know he won't listen.

Comment: Go to HR over the duct tape...no. Go to law enforcement? Yes.

Comment: @Walfrat Good point.

Comment: Do not engage directly with this person.  It is not your place.  Do engage with HR, your management etc.  Let them deal with it, that is their job.

If you have to park in the visitor spot again, put a note on your car that says this is not the dickhead that usually parks here, I have permission, go find his car if you have an issue, it's the one double parked somewhere.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers address the business part, but a thought is to put a sticker or something on the back windshield or get like a sun shade or something that will distinguish your car from the other persons.  It sucks that the situation exists in the first place, but there are things that you can do to make your car look different.  Also things on the antenna that blow in the wind.  Anything to distinguish your car from his and then let people know you added it to your car to distinguish it.

Obviously this is a partial solution as you want to address the professionalism issues, but the other responses cover that well, just adding this as you might want to adjust your car appearance in little ways so that it's distinguishable and hopefully people won't attack your vehicle next time.

Comment: Yes! Tie a colorful piece of fabric on the antenna or something. It's a great idea.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, it really should not be your responsibility to talk to the offending colleague and ask them to stop being so inconsiderate. You mentioned in the comments that you have 400 people on site - in which case I'm presuming you may have some kind of Site Manager, or Site Services. Normally - things like parking would be their responsibility, so I'd make sure they know what's going on, are familiar with your registration and therefore know it's not you causing the problem. You should also ensure they're going to do whatever they can to find the actual offender and improve their behaviour.

The issue you do have to deal with though is the fact that there are baying mobs roaming the building, hunting down parking offenders. I'd be asking for a formal meeting with HR in regards this, and also to the duct tape as it could be classed as Criminal Damage. In English Law;

> A person who without lawful excuse destroys or damages any property belonging to another intending to destroy or damage any such property or being reckless as to whether any such property would be destroyed or damaged shall be guilty of an offence.

I, personally anyway, would not stand for someone damaging my property whether they thought I was in the wrong or not. The fact they seem to be okay with is **wrong**.

Answer (score 4):

First off, I agree with the comments, let your colleagues know that you did in fact not do the things your other colleague did. If they have problems reading a license plate, maybe advise them to get their eyes checked.

Secondly, I would advise for you to go to HR, and talk to him **with** HR, and not alone. If there are more people who have told him not to do so already, it's of no use for you to do the same thing.

Make sure HR know's what's up, let them figure out what to do with the problem and if your colleagues pick the wrong car again, make sure they fix it as well.

Comment: The point is that not only that colleague is out of order, but the ones to call *OP* out for it are. The behaviour of OP's colleague is unacceptable, but it should not be OP's problem to sort that out (and it does not look very promising, especially as OP is not the person in charge here). However, that other colleagues harass OP for that is even worse. This is effectively bullying. In more serious situations, such gang-ups do lead to drastic miscarriages of justice. I think deal first with the misguided communal wrath, and only then, if at all, consider the colleague.

Comment: Agreed. The problem are the people who are unable to read license plates and start bullying random people because of it. Those people should be called out, probably with HR. If they have a problem with the parking of some random other guy, that's THEIR problem and THEY have to solve it. Not some other random guy who owns a similar car.